# Проблемы с подключением typed.js

Tags: javascript

Возникли проблемы с подключением библиотеки typed.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Typed.js test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="typed-strings">
        <p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
        <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
    </div>
    <span id="typed"></span>

    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

и js

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    import Typed from 'typed.js-2.0.9';

    var options = {
      strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
      typeSpeed: 40
    }

    var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
});
```

Вот ошибки, которые выскакивают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот папка, в которой хранятся все файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$('document').ready(function() {
    import Typed from 'typed.js-2.0.9';` так нельзя писать :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
import Typed from 'typed.js-2.0.9';
```

Данная строка может находиться только в начале файла, но не внутри функции.

Так как скрипт выполняется сразу в браузере, то данная строка вообще не нужна. Поэтому для решения проблемы достаточно просто удалить ее.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var options = {
    strings: ["<i>First</i> sentence.", "&amp; a second sentence."],
    typeSpeed: 40
  }

  var typed = new Typed("#typed", options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.9"></script>

<div id="typed-strings">
  <p>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</p>
  <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните файлы jquery.js и typed.js локально (сейчас вы пытаетесь их получить из интернета, и это не получается) и подключайте как локальные скрипты.

к примеру, так:

```
   <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/typed.js"></script>
```